# Batch removal of users and comments without causing excess load on server

Tags: 7, users, comments

I have a basic shared hosting account and don't want/plan to upgrade anytime soon. Unfortunately, my site has been subjected to large scale attacks by spambots that have lead to the generation of thousands of spam comments and users. I would like to delete these, but deleting them in batches causes the server to crash, every time. What should I do to avoid these crashes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting up a View with [VBO](https://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations).

- Add a new users view
- Add a bulk operations field to the view
- Add a "Delete item" operation to the field settings
- Configure the field settings to process "1" per batch
- Add any other required exposed filters.

That will delete one user per batch run until finished, so should be fine on your server.

Comment: I installed the Administration Views module (drupal.org/project/admin_views) - this replaces the users listing page automatically and allows filtering too.